# MacOS Monterey Terminal CLI: "open" command does not change focus

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Has anyone encountered an issue in which Terminal.app is no longer able to switch focus to another application?

For example, typing in the command `open .` would have previously opened the current folder in Finder, and then switch focus to Finder (i.e. bring Finder to foreground). However, that no longer works, and no options/etc. seem to fix it.

Similar results with applications (e.g. `open /Applications/Safari.app/`) and URLs (e.g. `open http://www.google.com/`). The requested action takes place, but the OS' focus stays on Terminal.app.

Terminal.app has full Accessibility permissions, so that's not it.

Anyone else run into this and/or found a solution?

Running MacOS Monterey (12.0) on Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A ha!  I figured it out.

Seems that the "Secure Keyboard Entry" option was the culprit.  Turning it off fixed the "problem."  Turning it on reliably reproduces it.

Seems like that might be a feature and not a bug...

Comment: It is a feature. There have been several instances where I've been typing away, only to have another application suddenly grab focus, resulting in my keystrokes doing something I didn't intend them to do.

Comment: "Secure Keyboard Entry" is a specific tool to protect password entry and similar activities, it's not a thing you generally need or want.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer more than once. Just spent 3 hours trying to figure out why launching my game from iTerm2 would unfocus it and place it last in the cmd+tab list. Tried upgrading GLFW and all sorts of `NSApp` and `NSWindow` schenanigans. Turning off Secure Keyboard Entry worked like a charm.

Comment: For iTerm: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70609/what-does-the-secure-keyboard-entry-menu-item-in-terminal-app-do

Comment: Thank you!! This was driving me insane. For anyone else that needs to disable this for Iterm2, the option is in the "Iterm2" menu dropdown.

Comment: OMG thank you. This has taunted me for years.